# Calculate the overall attendance rate for each grade on each day?

Tags: sql, count, average, dml

Given the following table schemas, how would you figure out the overall attendance rate for each grade on everyday?

Table 1: attendance_details

| Column | Data Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| date | string | date of log per student_id, format is 'yyyy-mm-dd' student_id |
| student_id | integer | id of the student |
| attendance_status | string | Possible values are ['present', 'absent'] |

Table 2: student_details

| Column | Data Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| student_id | integer | id of the student |
| grade_level | integer | will be a value between 0-12 |
| date_of_birth | string | Student birth date, format is 'yyyy-mm-dd' |

I have comeup with the below solution and it is working fine.

```
SELECT C.grade_level, C.date, CAST (D.present as float)/ C.TOTAL as attendance_rate
From 
(SELECT B.grade_level ,A.date, Count(*)  as TOTAL
from test.attendance_details A, test.student_demographic B
where A.student_id = B.student_id 
GROUP BY B.grade_level, A.date) as C,
(SELECT B.grade_level ,A.date, Count(*)  as present
from test.attendance_details A, test.student_details B
where A.student_id = B.student_id and attendance_status ='present'
GROUP BY B.grade_level, A.date) as D
WHERE C.grade_level = D.grade_level
and C.date = D.date
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT SD.GRADE_LEVEL, AD.DATE
,SUM(CASE WHEN AD.ATTENDANCE_STATUS = 'present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ATT_CNT
,COUNT(AD.STUDENT_ID)TOT_CNT
,ATT_CNT/TOT_CNT ATTENDANCE_RATE
FROM ATTENDANCE_DETAILS AD
INNER JOIN STUDENT_DETAILS SD ON AD.STUDENT_ID = SD.STUDENT_ID
GROUP BY SD.GRADE_LEVEL, AD.DATE
```